# Set up stores with same theme and different css Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, css

My multistore is setup as

```
shop
|-app
|-lib
|-pub
|-var
|-website1
 |-app*
 |-lib*
 |-pub*
 |-var*
 |-index.php
|-website2
 |-app*
 |-lib*
 |-pub*
 |-var*
 |-index.php
```

Where `app*, pub*, ...` are symbolic links to the folders in `shop` and the `index.php` files are set to run the two different websites.

Both `website1` and `website2` are configured to use the same theme, but I want them to use different colors and so I need them to use two different .less files (`_block1.less` and `_block2.less`) instead of the common one `/shop/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/yume/web/css/magento/_block.less` they are using now.

Is there a way to do this with the stores set up as they are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained what I needed creating a new theme as explained in the magento documentation (probably obvious, but I'm still learning).

The second store is configured with the new theme, which inherits everything from the one I wanted to modify, except the web/css/magento_block.less file.